# Is this a good Design Approach to pass the base class object its collection elements

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In My Base class type `A`, I have the collection of another type `B`. While executing some private operations of class `B` I need to get value from some member's of class `A`.

What are the best practices to achieve this?

My Problem statement goes something like this :

```
public class VisualService : IVisualService
{

   private readonly IList<AbstractVisualServer> myVisualServers = 
         new List<AbstractVisualServer>();

   // .... Other Members.. Goes below
   ...
}


public abstract class AbstractVisualServer
{

    // Need to use some of the members from VisualService inside the 
    // VisualServer class (Abs Base is AbstractVisualServer)
    // Hence, needs to hold the instance of VisualService.

    private IVisualService VisualService;
}
```

Kindly suggest the best approaches for this. And what could be the potential problems associated with this kind of approach. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one or two methods in the child class that need references to the parent object, then you could pass a reference to the parent object to that method.

But if it is more pervasive (i.e. most of the methods in the child class need to access properties of their parent object) then you could simply maintain a reference to the parent object on the child.

We had a similar issue, and that is how we solved it.

Comment: Yes, i agree to your point, my object is more pervasive, but at the same time my parent object is too heavy. So i want the performance consideration. Also by this approach my objects are tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

This problem often arises when there is a hierarchy of classes and it's necessary for child nodes to be able to get to their parent nodes.

It's hard to say what would work best for you without more information, but you have a couple of options:

1. Do what you're doing now, i.e. have a field holding the reference to your parent node and track these references manually.
2. Have a field holding reference to your parent node and arrange classes so that this is performed automatically (this approach is explained below, although it has its drawbacks).
3. Have a separate class which will keep mappings of each child node to its parent and update it manually (if you want to avoid having an additional field in your child classes).
4. Have a separate class which would have to be used to add or remove child nodes from the parent collection and update these references. This would require that all insertions and removals are done through this class, instead of adding them directly using `myVisualServers.Add` or `myVisualServers.Remove`.
5. Have callers of these methods pass the reference to the parent class (like @tamijud suggested). This doesn't ensure that you will get the correct parent, or that callers will know this information at all.
6. Finally, if the `myVisualServers` collection is supposed to be immutable after the instantiation of the `VisualService` class, then it might simplify things because you could pass the entire collection inside the constructor and wire all references there.

If you want to make this assignment automatic, you can create your own "smart" `AbstractVisualServer` collection, which would perform this on insertion and removal of items. The problem with this approach, however, is that you are then tied to this specific implementation and cannot rely on other interfaces to do this for you (no-one guarantees that a different implementation of `IVisualService` will do the same).

In that case, I am presuming this is what you want to achieve:

```
Parent parent = new Parent() { Name = "Parent" };
Child child = new Child() { Name = "Child" };

// starting conditions
Debug.Assert(parent.Children.Count == 0);
Debug.Assert(child.Parent == null);

// adding a child should set its parent
parent.Children.Add(child);
Debug.Assert(child.Parent == parent);

// removing a child should clear its parent
parent.Children.Remove(child);
Debug.Assert(child.Parent == null);

// setting a parent should add that child to the collection
child.Parent = parent;
Debug.Assert(parent.Children.Contains(child));

// clearing a parent should remove that child from the collection
child.Parent = null;
Debug.Assert(parent.Children.Count == 0);
```

First, you need to create a custom collection class which will intercept `Add` and `Remove` methods:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Note that this is a custom private collection class
    private readonly ChildCollection _children;
    public ICollection<Child> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    private class ChildCollection : 
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Child>
    {
        private readonly Parent _parent;
        public ChildCollection(Parent parent)
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Child item)
        {
            // remove from previous parent
            if (item.Parent != null)
                item.Parent.Children.Remove(item);

            base.InsertItem(index, item);

            // assign the new parent
            item.Parent = _parent;
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            // this item no longer has a parent
            var item = this[index];

            base.RemoveItem(index);

            item.Parent = null;
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, Child item)
        {
            // remove from previous parent
            if (item.Parent != null)
                item.Parent.Children.Remove(item);

            base.SetItem(index, item);

            // assign the new parent
            item.Parent = _parent;
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            foreach (var i in this)
                i.Parent = null;

            base.ClearItems();
        }
    }

    public Parent()
    {
        _children = new ChildCollection(this);
    }
}
```

And the `Child` class would also have to be "parent-aware":

```
public class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private Parent _parent;
    public Parent Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _parent;
        }
        set 
        {
            if (_parent == value)
                return;

            if (_parent != null && _parent.Children.Contains(this))
                _parent.Children.Remove(this);

            _parent = value;

            if (_parent != null && !_parent.Children.Contains(this))
                _parent.Children.Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All your Assert points are valid, except "// setting a parent should add that child to the collection". My intention here is to improve the performance and refactor. I found that in side the parents class when add a child to its child collection we have to pass the parent instance for example :  " Parent parent = new Parent.